# COBOL Parser using javacc + PMD

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, cobol, pmd, javacc

I am using this [grammar](http://java.net/downloads/javacc/contrib/grammars/cobol.jj) to generate a COBOL parser.

I use javacc to generate the parser and Java Tree Builder to generate the AST from this grammar.

I am customizing a eclipse plugin called [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) to read a COBOL file and generate the AST. There is a UI called Designer that allow you to fill a AST from a source code.

When I try using the source code bellow, I have a error message:

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
net.sourceforge.pmd.PMDException: Error while processing [no filename].cbl
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:80)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.util.designer.Designer$DFAListener.actionPerformed(Designer.java:502)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.ast.ParseException: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.ParseException: Encountered "" at line 0, column 0.
Was expecting one of:

    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cobol.CobolParser.parse(CobolParser.java:35)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.parse(SourceCodeProcessor.java:90)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource(SourceCodeProcessor.java:136)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:75)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.ParseException: Encountered "" at line 0, column 0.
Was expecting one of:

    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.generateParseException(CobolParser.java:43571)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.jj_consume_token(CobolParser.java:43405)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.IdentificationDivision(CobolParser.java:3734)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.ProgramUnit(CobolParser.java:3527)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.CompilationUnit(CobolParser.java:3450)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cobol.CobolParser.parse(CobolParser.java:33)
    ... 40 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.ast.ParseException: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.ParseException: Encountered "" at line 0, column 0.
Was expecting one of:

    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cobol.CobolParser.parse(CobolParser.java:35)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.util.designer.Designer.getCompilationUnit(Designer.java:135)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.util.designer.Designer.access$1(Designer.java:132)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.util.designer.Designer$ShowListener.actionPerformed(Designer.java:475)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.ParseException: Encountered "" at line 0, column 0.
Was expecting one of:

    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.generateParseException(CobolParser.java:43571)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.jj_consume_token(CobolParser.java:43405)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.IdentificationDivision(CobolParser.java:3734)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.ProgramUnit(CobolParser.java:3527)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.CompilationUnit(CobolParser.java:3450)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cobol.CobolParser.parse(CobolParser.java:33)
    ... 39 more
net.sourceforge.pmd.PMDException: Error while processing [no filename].cbl
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:80)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.util.designer.Designer$DFAListener.actionPerformed(Designer.java:502)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.ast.ParseException: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.ParseException: Encountered " "*" "* "" at line 2, column 7.
Was expecting:
    "program-id" ...

    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cobol.CobolParser.parse(CobolParser.java:35)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.parse(SourceCodeProcessor.java:90)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource(SourceCodeProcessor.java:136)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:75)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.ParseException: Encountered " "*" "* "" at line 2, column 7.
Was expecting:
    "program-id" ...

    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.generateParseException(CobolParser.java:43571)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.jj_consume_token(CobolParser.java:43405)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.ProgramIdParagraph(CobolParser.java:3925)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.IdentificationDivision(CobolParser.java:3741)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.ProgramUnit(CobolParser.java:3527)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.CompilationUnit(CobolParser.java:3450)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cobol.CobolParser.parse(CobolParser.java:33)
    ... 40 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.ast.ParseException: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.ParseException: Encountered " "*" "* "" at line 2, column 7.
Was expecting:
    "program-id" ...

    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cobol.CobolParser.parse(CobolParser.java:35)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.util.designer.Designer.getCompilationUnit(Designer.java:135)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.util.designer.Designer.access$1(Designer.java:132)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.util.designer.Designer$ShowListener.actionPerformed(Designer.java:475)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.ParseException: Encountered " "*" "* "" at line 2, column 7.
Was expecting:
    "program-id" ...

    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.generateParseException(CobolParser.java:43571)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.jj_consume_token(CobolParser.java:43405)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.ProgramIdParagraph(CobolParser.java:3925)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.IdentificationDivision(CobolParser.java:3741)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.ProgramUnit(CobolParser.java:3527)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cpd.cobol.ast.CobolParser.CompilationUnit(CobolParser.java:3450)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.cobol.CobolParser.parse(CobolParser.java:33)
    ... 39 more
```

**COBOL CODE**

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
  *
   PROGRAM-ID.    GETNUMT.
  *
   DATE-WRITTEN.  04/04/90.
  *
  *    MODIFIED   10/18/97.
  *
  *        *******************************
  *        *                             *
  *        *     Judson D. McClendon     *
  *        *     Sun Valley Systems      *
  *        *     329 37th Court N.E.     *
  *        *     Birmingham, AL 35215    *
  *        *        205-853-8440         *
  *        *                             *
  *        *******************************
  *
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
  *
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
  *
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
  *
   FILE-CONTROL.
  *
   I-O-CONTROL.
  *
   DATA DIVISION.
  *
   FILE SECTION.
  *
  *
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  *
   77  WS-ESCAPE-FLAG              PIC  9(01)     COMP VALUE 0.
   77  WS-ERR-MSG                  PIC  X(30)          VALUE SPACES.
  *
   COPY GETNUMW.COB.
  *
   SCREEN SECTION.
  *
  *
  *                     I N P U T   S C R E E N
  *
   01  INPUT-SCREEN
           FOREGROUND-COLOR 7
           BACKGROUND-COLOR 0.
       03  BLANK SCREEN
           LINE 01  COLUMN 31  VALUE "G E T   N U M B E R".
  *
       03  LINE 03  COLUMN 01  VALUE "Enter Number: ".
       03  PIC  X(25)          USING NW-WORK-NBR.
  *
  *
  *                    O U T P U T   S C R E E N
  *
   01  OUTPUT-SCREEN
           FOREGROUND-COLOR 7
           BACKGROUND-COLOR 0.
  *
       03  LINE 05  COLUMN 01  VALUE "      Result: ".
       03  PIC  -(13).9(06)    FROM  NW-EXTRACTED-NBR.
       03           COLUMN 41
           PIC  X(30)          FROM  WS-ERR-MSG.
  /
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
  *
  *
  *             C O N T R O L   S E C T I O N
  *
   000000-CONTROL.
  *
       MOVE SPACES TO NW-WORK-NBR.
       DISPLAY INPUT-SCREEN.
  *
       PERFORM 000100-PROCESS
          THRU 000100-EXIT
           UNTIL (WS-ESCAPE-FLAG = 1).
  *
   000000-EXIT.
       STOP RUN.
  *
  *                    P R O C E S S
  *
   000100-PROCESS.
  *
       ACCEPT INPUT-SCREEN
           ON ESCAPE
               MOVE 1 TO WS-ESCAPE-FLAG
               GO TO 000100-EXIT.
  *
       PERFORM 003000-GET-NBR
          THRU 003000-EXIT.
  *
       IF (NW-NBR-ERROR-FLAG = 1)
           MOVE "NUMBER INVALID" TO WS-ERR-MSG
       ELSE
           MOVE SPACES           TO WS-ERR-MSG.
  *
       DISPLAY OUTPUT-SCREEN.
  *
   000100-EXIT.
       EXIT.
  *
   COPY GETNUMP.COB.
```

I am not a COBOL programmer and because of that, I did not understand what is wrong in this grammar.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many under estimate the complexity of building a conforming COBOL compiler or parser. This is **really hard** stuff, much
harder than for most other languages.

I think the basic problem here is that the JavaCC grammar you are using is only appropriate for parsing COBOL 
source in post "text manipulation" phase.

A typical COBOL compiler has a pre-step where comments and compiler directing statements are processed to generate
a source text suitable for subsequent parsing. The "text manipulation" phase drops comment lines, processes continuation
lines, processes `COPY` directives and builds compiler directives to guide subsequent compilation.

The program you are trying to parse still contains comment lines (the lines with '*' in column 7) and a couple
of `COPY` directives. Until you either remove these or build a pre-compiler to complete the text manipulation phase
of compilation, the grammar you have will not be very useful - except on the most trivial of programs.

The really bad news is that I have seen many COBOL grammars suitable for post text manipulation phase
parsing, but virtually nothing for conducting the text manipulation needed to make them useful!

**Note:** The JavaCC grammer contains `CommentLine()` but these are for COBOL Comment
Entries, which are obsolete coding constructs found in some older COBOL programs. This does not parse
a COBOL comment line (bad choice of naming by the author or this grammar). As noted earlier COBOL
comment lines would have been removed during text manipulation.

Comment: I will try to remove the comments to check if the AST is filled. tks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be struggling with the comments.
COBOL statements are "Column Sensitive", although I can't see that the grammar is going to be able to recognise column alignment.

- comments should be an * in column 7
- division and section headers start in column 8 e.g "IDENTIFICATION DIVISION"
- other statements start in column 12

Its strange that it is reporting an error on "[no filename].cbl", is that because you haven't saved the file that is being parsed in Eclipse?

Try aligning the columns and removing the comments.

Comment: Tks for your answer. I saw that this grammar seems not handle the position of tokens =/ [no filename].cbl is showed because I just copy/paste the source code in the GUI of PMD